# iphone: basic understanding of google map api

Tags: iphone, google-maps

ok let me admit something that I am a little bit lost in here

Can any body suggest me some startup tutorial to get some idea about google map api.
I tried this url

"http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-geolocaton-iphone.html" as mentioned in google map api documentation

but this url has been moved I guess
so Please suggest me some tutorial with

1) show basic google map (not mapkit)
2) show pins on map
3) show multiple pins on map
4) When user clicks on these pins something get displayed in some subview

Comment: are you building a native app? or web based app?

Comment: I need a view which display map and I can display pins in that view

Comment: see my answer for mapkit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you are building a native app then you can visit my blog post here for mapkit (its great!)
http://www.makebetterthings.com/blogs/iphone/add-maps-in-iphone-apps-mapkit/

if you are building a web based app and needs javascript / html tutorial then you can visit -

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/yourfirstmap.html

http://econym.org.uk/gmap/

Comment: I am not looking for the web based map development I need info how to use this in iphone

Comment: then please follow the link - http://www.makebetterthings.com/blogs/iphone/add-maps-in-iphone-apps-mapkit/